# Rails: How to implement a named scope that returns all Users that wrote at least one Message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, named-scope

Consider the following associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, :foreign_key => "publisher_id"
  scope :wrote_at_least_one_message, <??>
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publisher, :class_name => "User"
end
```

How could I implement the `wrote_at_least_one_message` named scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? The inner join would check for at least one entry in messages table. Distinct is to avoid duplicates.

```
scope :wrote_at_least_one_message, select('DISTINCT users.*').joins(:messages)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. First of all `select('distinct(*)')` returns error. I tried `joins(:messages).select('DISTINCT *')`, but the `select` part doesn't work (it returns duplicates).

Comment: you need to change it to `DISTINCT users.*`

Comment: yes. `scope :wrote_at_least_one_message, select('distinct users.*').joins(:messages)` should work